# List All Bluetooth and Beacon devices Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

I need an any 3rd Party library or something like that. I want to list all Bluetooth Devices. I have got a TEXAS Instruments CC2541 Bluetooth Module. I want to see all devices. After that I want to listen this device. I tried to do lots of things but I'm screwed up.

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example from TI's git [repository](https://git.ti.com/sensortag-ios-source-code-example/?OrderOnline=More%20Info&TICOM_AUTHLEVEL=3&TICOM_VALIDATE_INPUT=1):

You can find everything you need to discover BLE devices and how to connect them.